# Passing optional arguments to LaTeX commands with Lua

Tags: luatex, packages, package-writing, lua, xkeyval

The following tex document is compiled with LuaLaTeX engine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keytest}
\begin{document}
\myAddFunction[c=30,d=40]{10}{20}
\end{document}
```

This works fine and output to 100.0 as expected. Here is the code in `keytest.sty' file.

```
\ProvidesPackage{keytest}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function test(a,b,c,d)
local c = c or 3
local d = d or 4
  return a + b + c + d
end
\end{luacode*}
% ========= KEY DEFINITIONS =========
\define@key{someop}{c}{\def\mop@third{#1}}
\define@key{someop}{d}{\def\mop@fourth{#1}}
% ========= KEY DEFAULTS =========
\setkeys{someop}{c=3,d=4}%
% ========= Defining Command =========
\newcommand{\myAddFunction}[3][]{{%
  \setkeys{someop}{#1}
  \directlua{tex.print(test(#2,#3,"\mop@third","\mop@fourth"))}%
}}%
\endinput
```

I can also use other than `xkeyval` package. I am looking for default way of passing options to command by using Lua only (not using `xkeyval`  or other package). I think it is possible. How could it be done?

Comment: You can use [something like this](https://github.com/gucci-on-fleek/lua-widow-control/blob/48928e/source/lua-widow-control.lua#L1613-L1715C2) for mandatory arguments; for optional arguments, you'll need to use `token.get_next` and `token.put_next`.

Comment: Do you mean the keyval processing or the as the title says handling optional arguments? For the former, I think using `luakeys` would be easier than writing all of the relevant Lua out yourself.

Comment: Would the code with luakeys be simpler than with xkeyval? I will try. I am looking to store optional arguments in Lua Table and then use them in Lua function. This would be useful if say I have 10 optional arguments.

Comment: @JosephWright A full key-val parser would be a lot of work, but `for k,v in texkeys:gmatch"([^=,]+)=([^=,]+)" do t[k] = tonumber(v) or v end` would probably be sufficient for most packages. I'd say the optional argument stuff is the trickier part.

Comment: @MaxChernoff Indeed, hence pointing to `luakeys` (which does all of that work)

Comment: I think explaining the _motivation_ would be useful here: I can see wanting to parse in Lua if all of the work is being done there (Say reading a file), but if you have TeX tokens as input, parsing in Lua simply looses important information (think say `[{,},{a=b}=c]`.)

Comment: There is also the `lparse` package: https://ctan.org/pkg/lparse